# JavaScript array - push multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
message_list = [
    {
        "Main_body": "test msg",
        "emp_name": "test",
        "emp_salary": "5000 USD"
    }
]
```

Its length (e.g., `message_list.length`) is 1.

Now I have another array like this:

```
added_user_data = [
    {
        "PostSharedLog": {
            userids: "2,4,5"
        },
        "created": "2123123"
    }, 
    {
        "PostSharedLog": {
            userids: "3,1"
        },
        "created": "2123147"
    }
]
```

Its length (`added_user_data.length`) is 2.

I want to push the above array `added_user_data` into `message_list`.

I tried doing it inside a `for` loop, now since the length of message_list is `1`, for the second iteration, the values do not get pushed since `message_list[1]` does not exist and is undefined. But I still want to create `message_list[1]` even if it does not exist.

if i do the below :

```
for(var k =0;<count(added_user_data.length);k++)
{
      message_list[k].PostSharedLog = added_user_data[k].PostSharedLog ; 
}
```

It only appends the first row from the array `added_user_data`  and gives an output like this when i print out `message_list` :

```
[{ 
        "Main_body": "test msg",
        "emp_name": "test",
        "emp_salary": "5000 USD", 
        "PostSharedLog": {
            userids: "2,4,5"
        } }]
```

The second iteration does not append anything at all .

I would like to see the below :

```
[{ 
            "Main_body": "test msg",
            "emp_name": "test",
            "emp_salary": "5000 USD", 
            "PostSharedLog": {
                userids: "2,4,5"
            },
            "PostSharedLog": {
                userids: "3,1"
            } 

 }]
```

Comment: There's no JSON here. JSON is a textual notation for data exchange.  If you're dealing with source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: *"But I still want to create message_list[1] even if it does not exist."* What rules apply to that? Why stop at adding one? What tells you you shouldn't add two? What final result do you want to see?

Comment: Also, this array is not "multi-dimensional".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - i have edited my question to add the output array and what i have tried .

Comment: @slimshady: What you've posted at the end cannot be created. You have an array with one entry in it, which is an object; that object has two properties with the same name. You can't do that, you can only have one property with a given name in an object. Your object initializer above would parse, but you'd end up with an object with just the latter `PostSharedLog` property.

Comment: (BTW, I didn't vote to close as a duplicate. I don't see how this is a duplicate of that question. But then, I don't think the question can currently be answered, either, so...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thanks for the expertise. Appreciate . Will have to find another way of achieving this i guess . :-(

Answer (score 0):

#### JSON objects can not have duplicate keys.

A JSON object is basically a `Map` it has `keys` and `values`. Each `key` in an object must be unique.

#### Invalid JSON

What you posted as your desired outcome can never exist because `PostSharedLog` can only exist once. Setting it again just changes the value.

Also `userids` is not a valid JSON key, it should be wrapped with `"` always!

Any [JSON linter](http://jsonlint.com/) will show you exactly why this is.

```
{ 
    "Main_body": "test msg",
    "emp_name": "test",
    "emp_salary": "5000 USD", 
    "PostSharedLog": {
        userids: "2,4,5"
    },
    "PostSharedLog": {
        userids: "3,1"
    } 
}
```

What you probably need to do is something like:

```js
{ 
    "MainBody": "test msg",
    "EmployeeName": "test",
    "EmployeeSalary": { "amount": 5000, "currency": "USD" }, 
    "PostSharedLog": {
        "UserIds": [2,4,5,3,1]
    }
}
```

#### NOTES:

1. Your names are not consistent. Really? Every one of them is a different *format*?
2. Do not abbreviate.
3. Do not store multivalue fields in `String` types, use a real `Array`! `[1,2,3,4]` instead of `"1,2,3,4"`
4. Do not store mutlivalue fields in `String` types, use a real `Object`! `{ amount: 5000, currency: "USD" }` instead of `"5000 USD"`